# Hive: create table statement where column formatted [k1:v1,k2:v2] is a map

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have tab-separated output from a Mahout recommender that I'd like to query in Hive. The recommendations look like this:

```
54508 [19:4.9,22:3.5]
54584 [17:5.2]
54648 [13:6.1,3:5.9]
54692 [17:8.1]
55424 [1:3.8]
55448 [16:2.7,3:1.2]
55452 [17:6.8]
57084 [42:6.8,3:5.4]
57212 [17:3.5]
```

There are two columns: the first column contains a userID, and the second contains a list of recommended products and their expected ratings.

I created a Hive table:

```
CREATE TABLE `recommendations_raw`(
  user int, 
  recommendations string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/etl/recommender/output';
```

And I'm able to transform the data into a long tabular form in a Hive query:

```
select
   user,
   product,
   rating
from recommendations_raw
lateral view explode(str_to_map(substr(recommendations, 2, length(recommendations) - 2), ",", ":")) product_rating as product, rating

user    product   rating
54508   19        4.9
54508   22        3.5
54584   17        5.2
[etc...]
```

However, I would have preferred to create the map inside the create table statement instead of using `str_to_map` inside the query since it seems wrong to create a table with `string` datatype when it's really a `map`.

Is this possible/practical? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in essence, you are using an EXTERNAL TABLE on a TEXT datafile produced by a non-Hive program (Mahout in this case).

**If** the file format was compatible with the way Hive serializes its MAP data type in TEXT (which is not the case because of the enclosing brackets), I guess you could just "map" a MAP column *(excuse the pun)* on that list of `key:value`.
Google pointed me to [that post](https://snehalatastechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/complex-data-types-in-hive/) for example.

But anyway, TEXT is TEXT. Hive has to deserialize the map on every read, whether implicitly (in the case of a MAP column definition) or explicitly (in case of a STRING column plus user-defined  `str_to_map()`).

Bottom line: if your goal is simply to explode the list and feed another table with a "normalized" structure, as shown in your sample code, then your solution with `str_to_map()` is better because it is more versatile (can manage the brackets...!)